# How to divide an image into blocks in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a 256x256 image and I want to divide it into 4 blocks of 128x128 each and address them as A1 to A4. Now I want to call them separately and do some operations on them. I know this can be done using the `blkproc` function -- but how exactly?

Do I call `blkproc` like this?

```
B=blkproc(I,[4 4],?)
```

What do I put in place of the "?", and how can I address the 4 blocks created?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since [`blockproc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html) (and the deprecated `blkproc`) are both functions in the [Image Processing Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/products/image.html), I thought I'd add a basic MATLAB solution that requires no additional toolboxes...

If you want to divide a matrix into submatrices, one way is to use [`mat2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) to break the matrix up and store each submatrix in a cell of a cell array. For your case, the syntax would look like this:

```
C = mat2cell(I, [128 128], [128 128]);
```

`C` is now a 2-by-2 cell array with each cell storing a 128-by-128 submatrix of `I`. If you want to perform an operation on each cell, you could then use the function [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html). For example, if you wanted to take the mean of the values in each submatrix, you would do the following:

```
meanValues = cellfun(@(x) mean(x(:)), C);
```

The first argument is a [function handle](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-handles.html) to an [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) which first reshapes each submatrix into a column vector and then takes the mean. The output is a 2-by-2 matrix of the mean values for each submatrix. If the function you pass to `cellfun` creates outputs of different sizes or types for each cell, then `cellfun` will have a problem concatenating them and will throw an error:

```
??? Error using ==> cellfun
Non-scalar in Uniform output, at index 1, output 1.
Set 'UniformOutput' to false.
```

If you add `..., 'UniformOutput', false);` to the end of your call to `cellfun`, then the output in the above case will instead be a 2-by-2 *cell array* containing the results of performing the operation on each submatrix.

Answer (score 7):

[`blockproc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html) is the new name for `blkproc` (which is deprecated). It can be used to apply a function to each block in an image. For example, if you wanted to divide a matrix I into 8x8 blocks and calculate the mean of each block, you would do this:

```
B=blockproc(I, [8 8], @(x) mean(x.data(:)));
```

B is then a matrix containing the means of the blocks.

Two things to note here:

- The specifier `[8 8]` specifies the *size* of the blocks, not the *number* of blocks.
- You don't get access to the blocks themselves outside of the function you pass to `blockproc`. If you need the blocks themselves, you have to do as Adrien suggested:

  ```
  A1=I(1:128, 1:128);
  A2=I(129:256, 1:128);
  A3=I(1:128, 129:256);
  A4=I(129:256, 129:256);
  ```

  Of course, in a real program, you should probably do this using a loop.

Comment: If you're still using an old version of the Image Processing Toolbox with the BLKPROC function, the syntax of the above example will change to: `B = blkproc(I, [8 8], @(x) mean(x(:)));`

Answer (score 3):

If `myImage` is your 256x256 image, wouldn't it be

```
image_top_left = myImage(1:128,1:128);
image_top_right = myImage(1:128,129:256);
image_bottom_left = myImage(129:256,1:128);
image_bottom_right = myImage(129:256,129:256);
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Its it better for you to make your program work for all sizes of images not just for 256*256.

```
[row, col]=size(your_image);
mr = round(row/2); % median of rows
mc = round(col/2); % median of columns
% Now divide your image and call each of them separately and do what ever you   want
top_left  = your_image(1:mr  , 1:mc);
top_right = your_image(1:mr  , (mc+1):col); 
bot_left  = your_image((mr+1):row , 1:mc);
bot_right = your_image((mr+1):row , (mc+1):col);
% final stage is to combining these parts again to return to its original shape 
Back_to_original = [top_left,top_right ; bot_left,bot_right]; `
```

hope this will be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to divide the image into squares of size gs ( e.g. 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,…), you can use the following code. This function extracts gs by gs patches from the input image and stores them into 'patch' variable. Notice that, if width or height of the input image is not a multiple of gs, then an offset equal to residual of the division won't be covered in patch extraction.

```
function [ patchim , npatchim ] = divideimage (im , gs)
 imheight=size(im,1);
 imwidth=size(im,2);
maxgsrow =  floor( imheight / gs);
maxgscol =  floor( imwidth / gs );
npatch = 1;
for i = 1 : maxgsrow
  for j = 1 : maxgscol
    rmin = ( i - 1 ) * gs + 1;
    rmax = i * gs;
    cmin = ( j - 1) * gs + 1;
    cmax = j * gs;
%%%%%%    do processes
    patch ( : , : , : , npatch) = im( rmin : rmax , cmin : cmax , : );
    npatch = npatch + 1;
  endfor
endfor   
 npatchim = npatch - 1;
patchim = patch;
end
```