# breaking an n*m image into p*q block in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am working on a project, but i am facing a problem: I have an image of size m*n(560*585) i need to break it into blocks of size p*q(8*8) and also have to store these blocks in separate variables.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What would those variables be - a cell array? Also, how to deal with the fact that 585 can't be broken into block widths of 8?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how-to-divide-an-image-into-blocks-in-matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637000/how-to-divide-an-image-into-blocks-in-matlab). I'm flagging it as such. **UPDATE** Hmmmm... on second thought, perhaps not, there are some slight differences as mentioned in the comment of @s.bandarathat that OP needs to clarify...

Comment: Also, come to think of it: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) I do have a function that solves this problem and doesn't require the image processing toolbox, but you need to display some evidence that you've had a go at solving it yourself first!

Answer (score 1):

How about [`im2col`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html)? You can also use [`padarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/padarray.html) to pad the image so that its size be an integer multiplication of `p` and `q`.