# How to set matrix element to mean of surrounding elements?

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

I have a matrix `X` that represents an image that was affected by noise. I also have a boolean matrix `M` that represents which pixels were affected by noise. What I want to do is to set every 'corrupted' pixel to the mean of its eight neighboring pixels.

Corrupted pixels are guaranteed to always be surrounded by uncorrupted ones, and also none of the pixels on the borders of the image are corrupted. What function can I used to write a vectorised version of this?

Comment: Maybe you need median, not mean? Use `medfilt2`.

Comment: The answers to this question -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637000/how-to-divide-an-image-into-blocks-in-matlab -- will be of interest to you.

Comment: @Eddy_Em It looks like `medfilt2` does what I want with the exception that I only want to do that operation for specific pixels, not for the whole image.

Comment: Then simply make mask for needed region, after that multiply mask to matrix, you will get first matrix. Negate mask and multiply to original matrix: you will get second matrix. Make `medfilt2` to your first matrix and add result to second, you'll get what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably not the most effective solution, but it should work.

```
N = size(M, 1);
target_ind = find(M);
offset = [-N-1, -N, -N+1, -1, 0, 1, N-1, N, N+1];

area_ind = bsxfun(@plus, offset, target_ind);
X(target_ind) = median(X(area_ind), 2);
```

Since all corrupted pixels are guaranteed to be surrounded by pixels, we can rather easily compute the linear indices of each corrupted pixel's neighbors. Here I've assumed that `X` is a grayscale image.

If `I` has more than one channel, then we could loop over each channel and add an offset to 
`target_ind` and `area_ind` each time:

```
for i = 1:size(X, 3)
    chan_offset = (i - 1)*size(X, 1)*size(X, 2) % Add the number of elements in previous channels to get indices in the current channel
    X(target_ind + chan_offset) = median(X(area_ind + chan_offset), 2);
end
```

Comment: I understand how this works, but I have a small problem adapting it to RGB images. Obviously I need to apply this procedure three times, once for each channel. I tried doing `X(:, :, 1)(target_ind) = ...`, but this gives me an error: `() must be followed by . or close the index chain`. How can I fix this?

Comment: @PaulManta I've edited my answer to add one way for handling an image with multiple channels.

Answer (score 4):

For your situation, this should perform quite fast

```
fixed = conv2 (image, [1 1 1; 1 0 1; 1 1 1]/8, "same")
# mask is a logical matrix for the corrupted pixels
image(mask) = fixed(mask)
```

**Explanation:** a mean filter is done with the `conv2` function. To calculate the average of a pixel and its neighbors, the kernel used is `ones (3) / 9` which means that 1/9 of each pixel value is used to calculate the new value. Since you don't want to count the center pixel in the average, you make its value 0 (in the kernel), and the others to 1/8.

Comment: @PaulManta since it seems you're dealing with RGB images, you can use `convn` instead of `conv2`. You'll have to adjust the kernel but the principle is the same. `kernel = zeros(3,3,3); kernel(:,:,2) = 1/8; kernel(2,2,2) = 0`

Comment: Just a small typ: 'same' instead of "same" :D Just saying, as there might be ppl not getting it :)

Comment: @tim it is not a typo. The questions is tagged with Octave as well, and double quotes strings are valid syntax there.

Comment: Quick question, if I wanted one neighbor element to have double the influence of the others, say fixed = conv2(image,[1 2 1, 1 0 1, 1 1 1]/9), it seems that the result isn't the mean of the neighbor values. What's am I doing/interpreting wrong? Maybe what I want can be done by simply: A(:).*B(:)./sum(sum(B))?