# How do filter 2D arryas or image only using 'filter' function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, filter

First, I want to make function that returns average value of 5 adjacent elements of 2d array. and then I'll filter image file by using it.

if I don't use filter2, imfilter function, How can I filter 2d arrays or image?
In that case, I think I should for loop, but I don't know how to do.

Pleae answer me~~

Comment: What have you tried so far? `filter` could for example be achieved easily using `for`-loops. Do you know what is the algorithm behind imfilter? There are pretty many image filtering algorithms on the internet, freely available to get the basic idea! And about the first part: How do you want to compute the average of 5 elements in a 2D matrix? Do you want to use the middle value and the 4 neighbours?

Comment: For the first part: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15586533/701049 This could quite easily be adapted to work for your computation of the kernel. And to convolute the kernel with your image, this should give you a basic idea: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)#Convolution which could be easily coded in MATLAB. Try on your own please.

Comment: Oh... That is too hard for me.

Comment: Then leave it or buy the Image Processing toolbox.

Comment: Or give me money to do it for you ;-)

Comment: Oh... That is too hard for me.
I tried first question

function y=hw3(x,n)
[m p]=size(x);
a=1;b=(1/n).*ones(1,n);  
                     
for k=1:p                     
    filtered_x(:,k)=filter(b,a,x(:,k));
    y(:,k)=filtered_x(:,k);
end

In this case, filter function compute average of 5 neighbour elements in column direction

Thank you for reply, but for me, it is too hard .....

Comment: I should use filter function and for loop etc, and should not use imfilter and fspecial, filter2.

Your solution doesn't use filter function