# Matlab Divide Image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a single image which contains 3 images 1 underneath the other.

Is there a way I can divide the image into three equal parts?

Comment: Are you talking about the rgb format when you say you have "3 images 1 underneath the other?"

Comment: no its grayscale image and i want to split into three equal seperate images

Answer (score 1):

you can use imcrop. reffer to this article: [how to segment an image in matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/46699)

and this on stackoverflow: [how to divide an image in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637000/how-to-divide-an-image-into-blocks-in-matlab)

Answer (score 0):

```
rgb = imread('ngc6543a.jpg');
r = rgb(:, :, 1);
g = rgb(:, :, 2);
b = rgb(:, :, 3);
```

Comment: when I try this it gives error "index exceeds matrix dimension" is it because its a graycale image

Comment: grayscale image is 2D matrix, but the question is about 3D matrix: "3 images"