# how to divide image into 8x8 and 32x32 blocks in matlab

Tags: matlab, block

image 'lena.tif' it have to divided into 2 blocks with size 8x8. In every of those blocks should be calculated the average value and standard deviation, after that save these result in one image with size 32x32. visualize images and interpret the result ?

[image]

please help me with full solution  because I'm beginner in matlab

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to divide an image into blocks in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637000/how-to-divide-an-image-into-blocks-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean: divide the 256x256 image into 8x8 blocks; for each compute mean and standard deviation; and save results as 32x32 matrices.

This can be done very easily with [`blockproc`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/images/ref/blockproc.html):

```
%// Load image
im = double(imread('lena.png')); %// 256x256 grayscale image

%// Compute block mean and std
m = blockproc(im, [8 8], @(b) mean(b.data(:))); %// 32x32 matrix of block means
s = blockproc(im, [8 8], @(b) std(b.data(:))); %// 32x32 matrix of block std's

%// Normalize to [0,1]
m = m-min(m(:));
m = m./max(m(:));
s = s-min(s(:));
s = s./max(s(:));

%// Write
N = 256; %// number of levels for writing m and s
imwrite(m*N, gray(N), 'lena_mean.png') %// save m as N-level grayscale image
imwrite(s*N, gray(N), 'lena_std.png') %// save s as N-level grayscale image
```

Resulting images:

- Mean

  [image]
- Standard deviation

  [image]

Comment: Thank you so much  @LuisMento ( sorry for my bad explanation :/ )