# location of person in the Image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, localization, location, detection

How can I divide the room into many zones and then find the location of a person in which zone.

I am using background subtraction in matlab for detect the person in the room, so can I extend this work to find out the location of the person in the image or even in the zone if I divide the image into many zones??

Thanks for your help
Regards

Comment: Share your code and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Dividing an Image into Subsections

The approach I provide here is just a slightly modified version of [another StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1637344/5209610).

> If you want to divide a matrix into submatrices, one way is to use the [`mat2cell` function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) to break the matrix up and store each sub-matrix in a cell of a cell array.

Take this example, where a 60x50 matrix is divided into 6 matrices in a cell (as shown in the image below):

```
C = mat2cell(I, [10 20 30], [25 25]);
```

[image: Splitting a larger matrix into smaller matrices]

More generally, to split your image into equally-sized "zones", the below will work:

```
im_rows = 256; % Replace this with the number of rows in your image
im_cols = 256; % Replace this with the number of columns in your image
C = mat2cell(I, [im_rows/2 im_rows/2], [im_cols/2 im_cols/2])
Zone1 = C{1,1};
Zone2 = C{1,2};
Zone3 = C{2,1};
% ... and so on
```

`C` is now a 2-by-2 cell array - 4 "zones" - each storing a quarter of your original image, `I`.

### Detecting People Within an Image

Now that you have split your image `I` into several zones, you can start detecting people within each particular zone.

If you have access to the `vision` package for MATLAB, then you can take advantage of the [`PeopleDetector` object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.peopledetector-class.html). Per the documentation, the `vision` package makes it exceedingly simple to detect people.

```
% Create PeopleDetector object
peopleDetector = vision.PeopleDetector;
% Read your image of question into MATLAB
I = imread('visionteam1.jpg');
% Detect people in your image
[bounding_boxes,scores] = step(peopleDetector,I);
```

> The `step(peopleDetector, I)` method returns an M-by-4 matrix defining M bounding boxes, where M represents the number of detected people. Each row of the output matrix, `bounding_boxes`, contains a four-element vector, `[x y width height]`. This vector specifies, in pixels, **the upper-left corner and size**, of a bounding box. When no people are detected, the step method returns an empty vector. The input image, I, **must be a grayscale or truecolor (RGB) image.**

If you would like the center position of each person that this function allows you to detect, you can perform some simple arithmetic:

```
center_x = x + width / 2;
center_y = y + height / 2;
```

Comment: thanks a lot, how can I divide the image or the room to several zones and name them as zone1, .... , zone N.??

Comment: @Mammo I have explained how to do exactly that in my recent post edit. Please read it above! :)

Comment: @ Vladislav Martin Really appreciate that, thank you so much

Comment: @ Vladislav Martin as I am using background subtraction to detect the movement of the person, could I find the location by this method (background subtraction) without using people detector package that found in matlab??

Comment: I would say so! I can't really go into details as to how you would do that, precisely, because I can't see your source code. Show me your approach and it would be much easier for me to give you a helpful answer (attach the source code where you perform the background subtraction and what not to your question)