# convert 3d matrix to 4d matrix using matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

I have 2D matrixs of dimensions 400 x 500,each of these matrixs show an image. my process contain 2 steps:

1) I have to partition these images (split matrix to equal sized sub-matrices)

2) I have to save each of these split in one matrix

first step is done and dimention of matrix change from 2D-->3D (the last index shows index of splits)

now for the step 2 I have 100 images and I want to have matrix with 4 dimensions which the last index show the number of images

sample : for accessing split 3 of image 40 : `[:,:,3,40]`

I already try to using permut and reshape but not successful

here is my code

```
nCol = 10;
nRow = 4;
K=dir(p);
Len=length(K);

for i=3:Len
    x1=imread(strcat(p,'\',K(i).name));
    [m,n,d1]=size(x1);
    if d1==1
        x=double(x1);
    else
        x=double(rgb2gray(x1));
    end
    x=imresize(x,NN);

   %% determined width and height of divided matrix %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 

   m = size(x,1)/nRow;
   n = size(x,2)/nCol;

   T = permute(reshape(permute(reshape(x, size(x, 1), n, []), [2 1 3]), n, m, []), [2 1 3]);

   Im=[Im T(:,:,:,i-2)];
end
```

any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have the 3D matrix of the new image in `T`, can you not store this in `Im` by changing your last line to `Im(:,:,:,i-2)=T`?

Comment: @Wolfie I tried that but no answer !!

Comment: Coming from Python, was about to tell you to fix your indentation :)

Comment: @Some Guy gave a very good answer below. It would be helpful to know what you intend to do with the processed images to know whether it will or won't matter what the output format is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reshape` picks elements in column major ordering so you might have to write convoluted code to get it to work.  Rather than going the way of using `permute` and `reshape` to create 4D matrices and potentially running into an out of memory issue I would advice the use of `mat2cell` to split your matrix into a cell array because `mat2cell` splits a matrix like you would want to split an image.

Here I show an example with an image

```
RGB = imread('peppers.png');
x = rgb2gray(RGB); % x is a 384 x 512 matrix, we want to split in 3 rows and 2 columns
x2 = mat2cell(x,384*ones(3,1)/3,512*ones(2,1)/2); % 2D cell array, each cell holds a part of the image
imshow(x2{1,1}) % Top left part of the image
```

You could loop over all your images and create a 3D cell array where each layer in the array represents each image split into pieces. I would suggest to preallocate you array and assign the matrix in the correct layer within the loop rather than incrementally increasing the size of your matrix.

Also there seems to be an Image processing toolbox specific function to do what you are trying to : Check this : [How to divide an image into blocks in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637000/how-to-divide-an-image-into-blocks-in-matlab)